# Looking for the name of this scale?

Tags: theory, scales

I'm looking for the name of the scale or rag using the following notes:

A B C C# D E F G#  and possibly a G when descending the scale.

It's coming from this song:

As it is from Pakistan I expect the name of a rag rather than a scale.
From a Western point of view it would be like a A Harmonic Minor with a Major third or a Dm Harmonic with a 7Maj. It is close to Saba scale one can found in Turkish/Greek but has some crucials differences.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Indeed i don’t see how to explain better than a A harmonic minor scale as from a western point of view. I’d be curious to get the name of the rag though as it’s used in a modal way.

Comment: Maybe you’ve transposed it, but I’m hearing different notes than the scale you list. I’m hearing C, D, D#, F, G, G#, B with passing tone of C#. Tonal center sounds like C or F. In any case I like it, but don’t have a name for it.

Comment: Yep sorry i forgot I was playing with a capo on 3rd fret ;)  Indeed the tonic (or Sa) is in C. I think the closest "scale" i found is a maqam called Sega with the third minor and major.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an A harmonic minor scale with a passing major third. A harmonic scale is minor scale with a raised seventh. So this scale would look like this:

[image]

However your scale, has an extra C#. That C# serves as a passing tone to the next note, D:
[image]

But, we can also think about this scale as a D minor bebop lydian dominant scale, with the F defining the minor third, bebop as the major seventh, lydian with the raised fourth, and dominant with the minor seventh.
[image]

But it gets too complicated after that so the A harmonic scale with a passing major third is the best way to think about it.

Hope that helps!